# How to change one property of a constructor without affecting others?

Tags: javascript

How to change one property of the constructor in the method "refactorGroupInfo", so that others would not be "undefined". Or how to make this method universal so that you can change one property of the constructor, or all

```js
class Group {
    constructor(nameGroup,course,specialization) {
            this.nameGroup = nameGroup;
            this.course = course;
            this.specialization = specialization;
    }
    refactorGroupInfo(nameGroup, course,specialization) {
        this.nameGroup = nameGroup;
        this.course = course;
        this.specialization = specialization;
    }
}
let Dev = new Group("D-11",4,"Front-end");
Devs.refactorGroupInfo("D-12");
console.log(Devs);
```

Comment: `Devs` is not defined.

Comment: It is really unclear what that method is supposed to do. Why not just write `Dev.nameGroup = "D-12";` if that's what you want?

Comment: I want to change the data about the group using this method. Either one parameter or several

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use an object, so every key you define inside is modified.

```js
class Group {
  constructor(nameGroup, course, specialization) {
    this.nameGroup = nameGroup;
    this.course = course;
    this.specialization = specialization;
  }

  refactorGroupInfo(object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach((x) => {
      this[x] = object[x];
    });
  }
}

const dev = new Group('D-11', 4, 'Front-end');

dev.refactorGroupInfo({
  nameGroup: 'D-12',
});

console.log(dev);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your refactorGroupInfo function, you could add a check to see if the parameters of the function haven't been defined.

```
refactorGroupInfo(nameGroup, course,specialization) {
    this.nameGroup = typeof nameGroup !== 'undefined' ? nameGroup : this.nameGroup;
    this.course = typeof course !== 'undefined' ? course : this.course;
    this.specialization = typeof specialization !== 'undefined' ? specialization : this.specialization;
}
```